# How to convert Hindi text DIV to PDF using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf-generation

I have an `DIV` and it contains some Hindi/Unicode/English text.

I want to convert this `DIV` to PDF, but the Hindi text does not appear in correct format.

How can I convert Unicode/Hindi text in HTML to PDF using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Added tag and cleaned up english/grammar.

Comment: Where you are "building" the PDF you need to make sure the right (Hindi) fonts are available.  If this is on the server, then make sure that server has the font you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to create a pdf written in any language as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="first">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="second">
<h3>Here is English, Spanish, Arabic, Hindi, Japanese, Korean and Assamese</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>I won't pretent to be the someone that I am not.</li>
            <li>No pretenderé ser el alguien que no soy.</li>
            <li>لن أتظاهر بأنني الشخص الذي لست كذلك.</li>
            <li>मैं वह होने का नाटक नहीं करूँगा जो मैं नहीं हूँ।</li>
            <li>私は自分ではない誰かのふりをするつもりはありません</li>
            <li>나는 내가 아닌 다른 사람인 척하지 않을 것입니다.</li>
            <li>মই যিজন নহয়, সেইজন হোৱাৰ অভিনয় নকৰো।</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="printContent()">Download PDF</button>

    <script>
//Adding print function
function printContent() {
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```